# Get Value From Ajax in C#

Tags: c#, php, ajax

In PHP I can get value from ajax with this code:
`$order = $_GET['order']`

What is source code in C# which has similar function with PHP code above?

Comment: In what context?  Are you creating a WCF in C#?  WebAPI? a simple web-forms .aspx page?  MVC controller action?  There are a multitude of ways of parsing querystring arguments - but your ultimate goal will likely dictate the correct answer.

Comment: I use MVC controller @Sean Murphy

Comment: Show us what you;ve done so far.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For a simple answer and not bothering to care about context, leverage the global `Request` object:

```
string order = Request.QueryString["order"];
```

For use in an MVC Controller action, declare it as an argument in the method:

```
public ActionResult GetOrder(string order) {
    // ... other code ...
}
```

Optionally you can define your route template if you want to have more concise control over the uri itself, including assigning a type constraint to the parameter:

```
[HttpGet, Route("orders/{order:int}")]
public ActionResult GetOrder(int order) {
    // ... other code ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create an object of key/value pairs and jQuery will do the rest for you:

```
$.ajax({
...
data : { name1: 'bar', name2 : 'foo' },
...
```

});

In controller:

```
public ActionResult GetOrder(string name1, string name2 ) {
 // ... other code ...}
```